# Node.js MSSQL package query function not returning data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I'm writing my first Node.js REST API. I'm using MS SQL Server as my database. I am using the npm package mssql to work with my SQL server DB.

I took the code below directly from the mssql docs example page. I simply wrapped it into a function.

```
 function getServices() {
  sql
    .connect(config)
    .then((pool) => {
      // Query

      return pool
        .request()
        .input("SID", sql.Int, 1)
        .query(
          "select * from [dbo].[Services] where ServiceId = @SID"
        );
    })
    .then((result) => {
      //console.dir(result); //this has data.
      return result;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return err;
    });
    }
```

The above code works just fine and gets the data from my DB. The issue happens when I try to make this code into a function that I can use on my express route, as shown below.

```
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  const data = getServices();
  console.log("data: ", data); //this comes back as undefined
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Handling GET request from /services router.",
  });
});
```

From reading the docs and all the others posts on stackoverflow. I am using the .then() promise mechanism, so why is my "result" not getting back to the function on my express route? The "data" const on the express route is always undefined. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept digging through some more SO posts and found my **working solution**. Updated, working code is posted below.

```
router.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  getServices().then((result) => {
    res.status(200).json(result.recordset);
  });
});


function getServices() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    sql
      .connect(config)
      .then((pool) => {
        // Query

        return pool
          .request()
          .input("SID", sql.Int, 1)
          .query(
            "select * from [dbo].[Services] where ServiceId = @SID"
          );
      })
      .then((result) => {
        //console.dir(result);
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        resolve(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: don't forget reject in your promise declaration ;-) return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thump: calling a function `const data = getServices();` means that this function doesn't contain any asynchronous work like async/await/.then/.catch/Promise.

Once a function containes one of those, it should always be called with one of the above.

SO #1 you must change

```js
router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  const data = await getServices();
  console.log("data: ", data); //this comes back as undefined
  res.status(200).json({
    message: "Handling GET request from /services router.",
  });
});
```

Then the function itself

```js
 function getServices() {
try {
  return sql
    .connect(config)
    .then((pool) => {
      // Query

      return pool
        .request()
        .input("SID", sql.Int, 1)
        .query(
          "select * from [dbo].[Services] where ServiceId = @SID"
        );
    })
    .then((result) => {
      //console.dir(result); //this has data.
      return result;
    })
} catch(ex){
return ex;
}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually just got it working with somewhat similar solution.